# Border radius 50% with concave border using pseudo elements

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I want to create a div with border-radius 50% and having blue background such that right side part of curve should be filled with another color say light blue. How do we do that using css pseudo elements

```
#circle{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Were is _your attempt_ to try and solve this? Simply position pseudo element absolutely, and make it half the width …?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following solution:

```css
#circle{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position:relative;
}
#circle:after {
content:"";
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
  background:lightblue;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```